# Get files name from directory and show in datagridview

Tags: .net

I can not display the same filenames in the datagridview. The only time Length has is showing me.

[image]

can you help me thank you... This is my code

```csharp
private void OdswiezOfer()
{
    string pathOO = (path + "\\" + id_inv);

    if (Directory.Exists(pathOO))
    {
        dgvOfer.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(pathOO).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();
    }
}

private void dgvOfer_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string id_inv = IdInv.Text;
    string filepath = path + "\\" + 
                      id_inv + "\\" +
                      (string)dgvOfer.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filepath);
}
```

Comment: Could you please try to explain in a bit more detail what your actual problem is? As the question stands now I honestly have no idea what you're talking about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the `length` of the string because if the dataGridView.DataMember defaults to the first public property of the type it is bound to which in the case of `System.String`, is the `Length`.

You could define a property on your `dataSource` and set the value you want, for sample `FileName`. You can use anonymous object to this:

```
string pathOO = Path.Combine(path, id_inv);
if (Directory.Exists(pathOO))
{

   dgvOfer.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(pathOO)
                                 .Select(x => new { FileName = Path.GetFileName(x) })
                                 .ToList();
}
```

The result (over `c:\windows`):

[image]